# converting png formatted text received from API to png file - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, format, qr-code

trying to make a program in python that request the following api and return with a QRcode.
this QRcode i get back is actually formatted text and i need to put that into a PNG file.
this is my code

```
import requests
import os


user = os.getlogin()
print("Hi there, " + user)
text = input("Enter a word: ")
request = requests.get("https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + text)
response = request.text

file = open("output.txt", "w")
file.write(response)
file.close()
print("\nDone !")
```

put i get this error when trying to save it as png or text:

`'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean when you say:

> this QRcode i get back is actually formatted text and i need to put
> that into a PNG file

The response you get is not plain-text. You can check the response headers' `Content-Type` field and confirm that it is an image (`image/png`). All you have to do is write the response bytes to a file:

```
def main():

    import requests

    text = "test"
    url = f"https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data={text}"

    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    with open("output.png", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)

    print("Done.")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: oh, never heard of .content ! let me try it out i get back to you...

Comment: yup the issue here was that i used .text instead of .content .
thanks ! i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad it's working! Also be aware of the write-bytes (`wb`) mode when writing to the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save response as png you can do it like this

```
import requests
import os

user = os.getlogin()
print("Hi there, " + user)
text = input("Enter a word: ")
request = requests.get(
    "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + text)

open(text+'.png', 'wb').write(request.content)

print("Done !")
```